# Significance of "@" in "ip a" command

Tags: centos, ip, network-interface, ifconfig

The output of the `ip a` command in CentOs 7:

```
259: veth2060b59@if258: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
    link/ether c6:1b:2a:b3:f6:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::c41b:2aff:feb3:f6c3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- **Why there is "@" in the interface name?**
- **What is the significance of it.?**

Note:

- Output of `ifconfig` command:

  ```
   veth2060b59: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet6 fe80::c41b:2aff:feb3:f6c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
          ether c6:1b:2a:b3:f6:c3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 1878  bytes 161872 (158.0 KiB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 3262  bytes 372175 (363.4 KiB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```

  - there is no "@" in interface.
- List of interfaces in `/sys/class/net`:

  ```
   [root@nix-lin415-01 net]# ls /sys/class/net/
   docker0  eno16777984  lo  veth2060b59
  ```

  - note that interface name is `veth2060b59` and NOT `veth2060b95@if258`.